# posting with js to api (asp.net core mvc )

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Hello im  using a DTO for  a single value(Id) &  trying to post to Db using  ApiController but on button click I  keep getting  error 400  that is referring me to  xhr.send error.
(im using asp.net core 2.1 ) 
Code :
@section Scripts{

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document)
            .ready(function() {
                $(".js-toggle-HandShake")
                    .click(function(e) {
                        var button = $(e.target);
                        console.log(button.attr("data-QuettaOfferId")); //Value=24 >>  OK 
                        $.post("/Api/HandShake/", { QuettaOfferId: button.attr("data-QuettaOfferId") })
                            // Error in > POST  https://localhost:44339/Api/HandShake/ 400 () & 
                            //in jquery>>  xhr.send( options.hasContent && options.data || null );
                            .done(function() {
                                button
                                    .text("Chousen");
                            })
                            .fail(function() {
                                alert("Something failed");
                            });
                    });
            });
    </script>
```

}
& the ApiController code

```
    [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Authorize]
public class HandShakeController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
  //  private readonly IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment;

    public HandShakeController(ApplicationDbContext context ,UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager/*, IHostingEnvironment environment*/)
    {

        _context           = context;
       _userManager       = userManager;
       //hostingEnvironment = environment;
    }

    [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.HttpPost]

 //   public IHttpActionResult HandShakes(HandShakeDto dto)
 public IActionResult HandShakes(HandShakeDto dto)
    {
        var userId = _userManager.GetUserId(User);
        var check = _context.Quetta.Where(u => u.SiteUserId == userId);

        if ( _context.handShakes.Any(f => f.QuettaOfferId == dto.QuettaOfferId))
            return BadRequest("Some  error Msg");

        if (check.Any())
        {
            var hand = new HandShake
            {
                QuettaOfferId = dto.QuettaOfferId
            };
            try
            {
                _context.handShakes.Add(hand);
                _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return Ok();
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                return BadRequest("Some error Msg");
            }


        }
        else{
             return BadRequest("");}


        //    Check if the user id that publish the ed = login user.
        //if so add the offer to selected table,
    }
}
```

im using asp.net core 2.1 & strongly suspect that the  problem is in the ApiController but im not sure.

The DTO

```
 public class HandShakeDto
{
    public int QuettaOfferId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Post also the `HandShakeDto` class

Comment: Your posting to `/Api/Hand`, but your controller is named `HandShakeController`, not `HandController`

Comment: Opps typo , I have updated it , Sorry .

Comment: And if you want to hit that method, then it would need to be `/Api/HandShake/Handshakes`

Comment: @StephenMuecke , I did tried that before(& now)  >https://localhost:44339/Api/HandShake/HandShakes 404 ()

Comment: What are the details of the error? And do you have any route definitions that may be affecting it?

Comment: @StephenMuecke  I only get> (jquery error) , it is not hitting the controller (breakpoint) jquery error>  xhr.send( options.hasContent && options.data || null ); & I didn't write any routs in my project -Yet

Comment: @StephenMuecke , you where absolutely right , the problem is "package microsoft.aspnet.webApi.core 5.2.6 was restore using .NetFramwork, version v.6.1 insted of the project target framwork NetCoreApp , version v2.1" Any known  work around ?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing 
    `$.post("/Api/Hand/", { QuettaOfferId: button.attr("data-QuettaOfferId") })`
By
    `$.post("/Api/HandShake/", { QuettaOfferId: button.attr("data-QuettaOfferId") })`

as your api controller name is    HandShakeController

Comment: Code is updated Im using handshake > POST https://localhost:44339/Api/HandShake/ 400 ()

Comment: In your api controller try changing  `public IActionResult HandShakes(HandShakeDto dto)` to  `public IActionResult Post(HandShakeDto dto)`

Comment: Or in your javascript try changing `$.post("/Api/HandShake/", { QuettaOfferId: button.attr("data-QuettaOfferId") })` to `$.post("/Api/HandShake/Handshakes", { QuettaOfferId: button.attr("data-QuettaOfferId") })` to hit the method in api controller

Comment: Have you registered controller dependencies correctly?  `public HandShakeController(ApplicationDbContext context ,UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager/*, IHostingEnvironment environment*/)`

Comment: thanks for your help but :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52151411/asp-net-webapi-core-not-compatible-with-my-project