# Asp.net WebApi.core not compatible with my project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

after asking "[posting with js to api (asp.net core mvc )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52147370/posting-with-js-to-api-asp-net-core-mvc) " & not finding solution I have discovered the the problem is with the API core library .
the error in the nuget Lib. is : Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 5.2.6' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project. 
 I assume im not the first one but I didn't find any work around . Any advice will be great .

Comment: Looks like you added the wrong package to your project. `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core` is *not* an ASP.NET Core package. How/why did you add it? The ASP.NET Core project templates add the correct package when you create a new project

Comment: do you think I should uninstall it ?

Comment: Yes. Why did you add it in the first place? The project templates already contain the correct packages. How did you create your application?

Comment: I did not add it manually .

Comment: You must have, either directly or indirectly by adding a *non*-Core package. To verify this just create a new folder and type `dotnet new webapi` to create a new Web API project. You'll see it *doesn't* add any such package

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Type where ? im not using CMD

Comment: @AssafOur: did you use the "nuget package manager"?

Comment: @Stefan yes , i think that resharper has install this for me . i did uninstall it

Comment: Not sure, but I made a similar mistake before. I think you need this package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore/

Comment: i have Microsoft.AspNetCore (2.1.1) & nuget doesn't suggest any update